# how to update react state to add an element in array, which is nested array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: "", age: "", phoneNumbers: [''] },
  ]);
```

if we need to add a new person, we can use following syntax...

```
  const addPersonFields = () => {
    let person = {
      name: "",
      age: "",
      phoneNumbers: [""],
    };
    setPersons([...persons, person]);
  };
```

But how to add new phone number for the person at index "i" and make that reflect in react state?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the index of the person you want to update, you could do something like:

```
const addPersonPhoneNumber = (index, newNumber) => {
    const newState = [persons];
    newState[index].phoneNumbers.push(newNumber);
    setPersons([...newState]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, we can add the phone number of a person at index `i` by using `setPersons` directly

```js
    const addPhoneNumber = (index, phoneNumber) => {
        setPersons((prevPersons) => {
            prevPersons[index].phoneNumbers.push(phoneNumber);
            return [...prevPersons];
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find the person at first. The solution below suggests you already have the person object you want to add a phone number to.

```
  const addPhoneNumber = (newNumber) => {
    let index = persons.map((e) => e).indexOf(person);
    persons[index].phoneNumbers.push(newNumber);
    setPersons([...persons]);
  };
```